# Using the counter as ID - is it a good idea in a smart contract?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

I have coded the following to keep track of deposits into a smart contract.
I need to be able to reference individual deposits in future functions.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

contract DepositsWithIds {
    address owner;

    struct Deposit {
        uint256 depositAmount;
        address depositor;
        uint256 counter;
    }

    constructor() payable {
    owner = msg.sender;
    }
  
    Deposit[] public activeDeposits;

    event DepositMade(address, uint256, uint256);

    function deposit() public payable returns (uint256 counter) {

        return ++counter;

        Deposit memory newDeposit = Deposit(

        msg.value,
        msg.sender,
        counter
    );

    activeDeposits.push(newDeposit);

    emit DepositMade(msg.sender, msg.value, counter);

    }
}
```

Is it a good idea to use the counter as a unique deposit ID?
How would you be able to connect `activeDeposits.counter` to `activeDeposits.depositor` when writing the next function?

Answer (score 0):

You could take the `counter` out of struct:

```
struct Deposit {
    uint256 depositAmount;
    address depositor;
}
```

You set the counter as top state variable

```
uint256 counter;
```

you could have a mapping that maps the counterId to `Deposit`

```
mapping(uint156=>Deposti) public idToDeposit;
```

then get the deposit by id

```
function getDepositByID(uint id)public view {
     idToDeposit[id]
}
```

- you might come across of [openzeppelin Counters.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/Counters.sol) to use the counter

you install `npm i @openzeppelin/contracts`, import the ``Counters

```
 import "../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
```

in your contract:

```
contract Test{
       // this means all Counters.Counter types in your contract loaded with the methods of Counters library
       using Counters for Counters.Counter;
       Counters.Counter private depositIds;
}
```

Comment: I don't see the point of using a separate library for a basic ```uint256 ++counter``` variable. So I took the counter out of ```struct```, added as a state variable, and added the mapping you suggested. What would be the function to find a particular deposit by inputting an ID, and where to find that ID?

Comment: I mentioned the library in case you might have seen it. it is gas efficient but you wont need here. what do you mean by `particular deposit`.  you want to look for a particular deposit but what will be your search criteria. `by address` maybe?

Comment: By particular deposit I mean that if a person makes a deposit, I need to be able to look up exactly that deposit. One address can make many deposits, so searching by address is not valid. Therefore every deposit should have a unique depositId. 

```function transfer (uint256 counter) public {activeDeposits[id].depositor.transfer(activeDeposits[id].depositAmount);}
```
So basically this function would have to transfer the deposited amount to the person who made the deposit with information based on deposit ID.

Comment: that is what mapping comes into play. mapping is like a dictironary in python or object in javascript. `idToDeposit[particularId]` will give you the `Deposit`

Comment: so ```[particularId] = counter```?

Comment: yes. whichever id you want to look up

Answer (score 0):

```
uint public counter;

mapping(uint = > Deposit) public ids; 

function deposit() public payable {

    Deposit storage _deposit = ids[_counter]; 

    _deposit.depositAmount = msg.value; 

    _deposit.depositor = msg.sender;
    
    activeDeposits.push(_deposit);

    _counter++; 

    emit DepositMade(msg.sender, msg.value);
}
```

Comment: Here you are using both a counter and mapping. Can you use just one or the other?

Comment: Also, I created a new thread with updated code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74730493/what-is-the-best-way-to-assign-an-id-to-a-deposit

Comment: In this case you need to use both, counter variable to actually count deposits and mapping to storage every single deposit.