# What is the best way to assign an ID to a deposit?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

What would be the best way to get an id for the releaseDeposit(id) function? I know there are a few options, such as using counters or mapping, however, is there one that would be the preferred way, and how would it be implemented?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The code in question:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

contract DepositsWithIds {
    address owner;

    struct Deposit {
        uint256 depositAmount;
        address buyer;
        address seller;}

    constructor() payable {
    owner = msg.sender;}

    Deposit[] public activeDeposits;

    function deposit(address seller) public payable {

        Deposit memory newDeposit = Deposit(

        msg.value,
        msg.sender,
        seller);

    activeDeposits.push(newDeposit);

    function releaseDeposit(uint256 id) public {

        require (msg.sender == activeDeposits[id].buyer,
        "Only maker of the deposit can release deposit.");

        payable(activeDeposits[id].seller).transfer(activeDeposits[id].depositAmount);}
}
```

Comment: Do you need id to be for every deposit that user provide or to be the key for user whole information? And when user release deposit i presume all funds that were stored transfering to seller, right?

Comment: A unique ID has to be for every deposit (the deposit simply consists of ```depositAmount```, ```address seller``` and ```address buyer```, however, there can be a few deposits made with these same details, so it would be better if they had separate IDs). And when buyer releases, yes, all funds go to the seller, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its better to use mapping instead of arrays, thus i deleted array and make everything working via mapping. You can test it in remix and make sure its working like you need.

```
contract Escrow {

address owner;
uint public _counter; 

struct Deposit {
    uint256 depositAmount;
    address buyer;
    address seller;
}

constructor() payable {
owner = msg.sender;
}

mapping(uint => Deposit) public ids; 

event DepositMade(address depositor, uint depositAmount);

function deposit(address _seller) public payable {

    require(msg.value > 0, "error"); 

    Deposit storage _deposit = ids[_counter]; 

    _deposit.depositAmount = msg.value; 

    _deposit.buyer = msg.sender;
    
    _deposit.seller = _seller; 

    _counter++; 

    emit DepositMade(msg.sender, msg.value);
}

function releaseDeposit(uint256 id) public {

    require (msg.sender == ids[id].buyer, "Only maker of the deposit can release deposit.");

    payable(ids[id].seller).transfer(ids[id].depositAmount);
}

}
```

Comment: Nice that you removed the array, as I understand mapping uses less gas. However, to run the function ```releaseDeposit(uint256 id)``` I need to input ID to reference a deposit. But the ID is not declared anywhere when making the deposit. Therefore, when callin ```releaseDeposit(uint256 id)``` the contract has no idea of knowing which deposit to release. How to make it so that calling ```deposit(_seller)``` the deposit gets assigned a unique ID that can be referenced to when calling ```releaseDeposit(id)```?

Comment: When you making first deposit, contract take _counter variable and assign to it deposit struct, and after increase _counter, so the next deposit that you make will be separate. So when you want to release it, you calling releaseDeposit(uint id), put id of your deposit, that you made, after contract check mapping which contain struct under this id, and send funds to seller. You can make several deposits from your address and every single one will have own id.

Comment: Deposit assigned to variable counter, thus ids start with 0,1,2,3 and so on. You want them to be special random set of numbers for each deposit? Like "7452" for example?

Comment: Please clarify whole logic.

Comment: Everything runs super smooth now, thanks! I'm just thinking for the final touch - it would be way more practical to use transaction hash instead of the counter as an ID! Don't you think? How would you implement that?:)

Answer (score 1):

Using hash instead of counter variable.

```
contract Escrow {

address owner;

struct Deposit {
    uint256 depositAmount;
    address buyer;
    address seller;
}

constructor() payable {
owner = msg.sender;
}

mapping(bytes32 => Deposit) public depositByHash; 

event DepositMade(address depositor, uint depositAmount, bytes32 hash);

function deposit(address _seller) public payable returns(bytes32) {

    require(msg.value > 0, "error"); 

    bytes32 hash = keccak256(abi.encode(msg.value, block.timestamp, _seller)); 

    Deposit storage _deposit = depositByHash[hash]; 

    _deposit.depositAmount = msg.value; 

    _deposit.buyer = msg.sender;
    
    _deposit.seller = _seller;  

    emit DepositMade(msg.sender, msg.value, hash);

    return hash; 
}

function releaseDeposit(bytes32 hash) public {

    require (msg.sender == depositByHash[hash].buyer, "Only maker of the deposit can release deposit.");

    payable(depositByHash[hash].seller).transfer(depositByHash[hash].depositAmount);
}
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is necessary to create a separate hash, as every transaction already has its own hash, only need to access it.

Comment: Do you know how to implement this?

Comment: Looking for a way, but it must be possible.